# Jest Unit Test Singleton class Nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, singleton

i have below code where i am tryin to unit test a function which is using class variable of the singleton class

**Singletonclass a.js**

```
class A{
constructor(){
   this.flag = true;
 }
 
setA(){
  this.flag=false;
  }
}

module.exports = new A(); //Singleton
```

**Class using Singleton Class**

```
import A from './a';

class B {
  constructor() {}

  hello() {
    if (A.flag) {
      console.log('1');
    } else {
      console.log('2');
    }
  }
}
```

**Unit test Case for b.test.js**

```
import A from './a' //Singleton class
import B from './'

describe('Test Hello', () => {
    const b= new B();
    
    beforeEach(() => {      
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    })


    test('Test Hello', async () => {        
        try{
            jest.spyOn(A, 'flag')
                .mockResolvedValueOnce(true);
            let output = b.hello();
                    
        }catch(e){
            console.log('Error', e);
        }
    });
});
```

So one line in b.js , console.log(1) is not getting covered in the coverage report. Tried multiple options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

1. You are testing the `b.js` module, not the `a.js` module. So the test file name should be `b.test.js`.
2. The imported module name is wrong. It should be `./a.js`, not `A.js`.
3. If you want to change the attributes of instance a, you only need to assign values ​​in the test case

E.g.

`a.js`:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.flag = true;
  }

  setA() {
    this.flag = false;
  }
}

module.exports = new A(); //Singleton
```

`b.js`:

```js
import a from './a';

export class B {
  constructor() {}

  hello() {
    if (a.flag) {
      console.log('1');
    } else {
      console.log('2');
    }
  }
}
```

`b.test.js`:

```js
import a from './a';
import { B } from './b';

describe('67335501', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should print "1"', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    a.flag = true;
    const b = new B();
    b.hello();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('1');
  });

  it('should print "2"', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    a.flag = false;
    const b = new B();
    b.hello();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('2');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67335501/b.test.js (10.808 s)
  67335501
    ✓ should print "1" (18 ms)
    ✓ should print "2" (2 ms)

  console.log
    1

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

  console.log
    2

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |    87.5 |      100 |      75 |    87.5 |                   
 a.js     |   66.67 |      100 |      50 |   66.67 | 7                 
 b.js     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.657 s
```

Comment: I added a random string `__debugRandomId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);` to the singleton class, and in `b.test.js` it shows the same.
However, in another test file `a.test.js` these two `__debugRandomId` in two tests are different, meaning they are not the same instance.

Is there any method to make them the same?